# Manipulating Data from html source code and converting to .txt file in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to write a program that takes the source code from a html file and manipulates the data. So far, I have been able to write code to strip all html code and output onto a .txt file which is great.

But I am struggling with the next part of my code. I am trying to model a class for entertainment review (the website I am taking info from is a blog about movie, play, and film reviews). I want to be able to make it organized so that the new .txt file will be sorted by the type of entertainment they watched (i.e. film, play, etc.), then display the cost of the movie and also show whether it was recommended or not. I have attached what some of the source code looks like below.

I really don't even know where to start here, or how to manipulate the data to be organized. I feel I am supposed to make a constructor that takes each line of data, but I could be wrong.

```
<p>Tonight I saw <em class="film">You Will Meet a Tall Dark Stranger,</em> a film by Woody Allen but without him anywhere in it. I'd say it's okay to see once, but not critical.... lots of intertwining relationship stories with endings you can never anticipate.
```

Comment: What you're trying to do is to get film's information from the txt file and then sort this txt file? What do you mean by 'the new .txt file will be sorted by the type of entertainment'?

Comment: Can you show what code have you implemented till now?

Comment: I would recommend using a Javascript engine like [Rhino](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino) and fetch the parts of the html you might require.